# The log4j2.xml file is not used in my Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j

I have a small Spring Boot application and try to use log4j2.

Here is what I did:

This is my build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'       
    }

dependencies {
...
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
...}
```

This is my log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${hostName} --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="de.myapp" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I placed the log4j2.xml in the same folder as my application.properties.

The log level stays at INFO. Which is what I guess the default level. It seems that the log4j.xml is not used. The log level should be DEBUG. I also tried to set the path to the log4j2.xml explicit with
-Dlogging.config='/path/to/log4j2.xml'. I also tried to put the log4j.xml in different folders. Nothing works and the log level stays at INFO. What is missing here?

---

Hi together, I am a step further now. I renamed my log4j2.xml to log4j-test.xml und now the basic logging and log levels work. Except for the logging under my own package. Here it stays on INFO no matter what.

Here is a snippet from my build.gradle:

```
   configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j'

}


dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.camunda.bpm.springboot:camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp:7.15.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
implementation 'com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc8:19.3.0.0'
implementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:4.2.0'
implementation 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.17.0'
implementation  'org.springframework:spring-jms'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq'
implementation 'axis:axis:1.4'
implementation files("${libs}/wf-externio.jar")
implementation files("${libs}/sad-wf-mapper.jar")
implementation files("${libs}/sad-util-lib-1.5.jar")


runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
runtimeOnly 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.3'
implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.1'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

It seems that there is another log4j.xml which I have to exclude. But I don't know where. How can I find that out and exclude it?

Comment: `logging.level.de.myapp=DEBUG` in application.properties is all you should need. No logging config files required. In your code: `Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);` and `import org.slf4j.*`;

Comment: I think I need that sice I want to have log4j2 instead og logback.

Comment: Why so? Logback is better

Comment: A fast way to check if your configuration file is used or not is to set `status="DEBUG"` and check the messages on your console. If there are no messages, another configuration file is used (e.g. a `log4j2-spring.xml` file).

Answer (score 0):

This is because by default Spring Boot uses Logback as a logging method. If you want to replace it with Log4J, you first need to exclude it from the dependencies of

> spring-boot-starter-web

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I did that already in my build.gradle:                                   
 exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'